# How to generate Click Once Deployment file .exe without depending on .application file?

Tags: c#, clickonce

In c#, How to generate Click Once Deployment file .exe without depending on .application file?

I have created Click Once Deployment file. It works great.

However, .exe file was created along with .application file and Application Files - Folder which has necessary files.

.exe file works only if it is available along with .application file in the folder. If i share the .exe file without .application file to another user, it throws an error as follows ..

How to make the .exe file independent without depending on .application file?

```
  + Downloading file:///C:/Users/MyAccName/Downloads/MyProject.application did not succeed.
            + Could not find file 'C:\Users\MyAccName\Downloads\MyProject.application'

MyProject.application.exe.manifest did not succeed.
```

Comment: _"`If i share the .exe file without .application file to another user`, it throws an error as follows ..`How to make the .exe file independent` without depending on .application file?"_ - Easy, just don't build it as a _ClickOnce_ app in the first place.

Comment: Check if using some tool like Fody you could bundle the .application in the .exe

Comment: It has to be Click Once App .. and .exe file is depending on few other files which is part of installation ( Including .sql file ).

Comment: What you ask is not possible.  I don’t understand why a tiny file is causing you issues